# Use Spring as a REST Client

Tags: scala, spring-boot, http-post, akka

How can I call following REST service from spring?

```
val route = post {
  path("notification" / "signUp"){
    headerValueByName("App_Key") { app_key => {
      handleWith {
        requestParameters: RequestParameters =>
              //application specific implementation
      }
    }}
  }
}
```

which contains App_Key and Content-Type in header and request parameters in json format.

Request parameters are like:

```
case class RequestParameters (
     var name: String,
     var email: String,
     var password: String)
```

So I have to call this REST service from java spring. I am struggling while calling http://ipadress:port/notification/signUp from java.

Comment: Explain in more detail what you are struggling with, instead of only saying that you are struggling. What does your code look like? Do you get an error? If so, then what is the error? See, for example, this tutorial: [Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

Comment: It isn't very clear how you're "mixing" akka, spring and scala.

Comment: @mfirry I want to call above REST call from Spring.